# Multiple colons and equal sign in makefile (need explanation)

Tags: makefile

This is only a segment of a makefile. I don't quite understand what is going on.

```
OBJS = $(SRCS:$(SRC)/%.cpp=$(OBJ)/%.o)
$(OBJS):$(OBJ)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.cpp | print-opts
    $(cc-command)
```

All I understand is these lines compile .cpp files into .o, after 'print-opts', with 'cc-command'. But I don't understand the semantics.

If I expand the macro of 'OBJS', this line should be:

```
$(SRCS:$(SRC)/%.cpp=$(OBJ)/%.o) : $(OBJ)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.cpp | print-opts
    $(cc-command)
```

To me, it looks like in '$(SRCS:$(SRC)/%.cpp=$(OBJ)/%.o)', it claims all .cpp in $(SRC) would come to .o in $(OBJ), but this would depend on $(OBJ)/%.o, which depends on $(SRC)/%.cpp. This doesn't make sense...

I don't understand what is the meaning of equal sign here, and what multiple colons mean.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Suppose you've defined these three variables (and if you haven't, the rule won't work very well):

```
SRC = source_dir
OBJ = object_dir
SRCS = source_dir/foo.cpp source_dir/bar.cpp
```

Now consider the assignment

```
OBJS = $(SRCS:$(SRC)/%.cpp=$(OBJ)/%.o)
```

This is a [substitution reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Substitution-Refs); it says "for anything in `$(SRCS)` that has the form `$(SRC)/%.cpp`, change it to `$(OBJ)/%.o`". So `OBJS` will evaluate to `object_dir/foo.o object_dir/bar.o`.

Now the rule:

```
$(OBJS):$(OBJ)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.cpp | print-opts
    $(cc-command)
```

Thuis is a [static pattern rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern). It specifies a list of targets (`$(OBJS)`), a target pattern (`$(OBJ)/%.o`) and a prerequisite pattern (`$(SRC)/%.cpp`). Make matches a target to the target pattern, and uses that to construct the prerequisite name. So if Make used this rule to build `object_dir/foo.o`, the stem would be `foo` and the prerequisite would be `source_dir/foo.cpp`.

(You didn't ask about `| print-opts`, so I assume that it's already clear.)

Comment: Thank you very much. The references to gnu 'make' manual are very helpful as well. (I had looked at that manual before, but I couldn't locate the information I needed)

Comment: Tad confused by the substitution reference. So if I have `main.c`, it will stick it into the object files directory and just change the the file extension to `.o`. This preserves the content of the file, and just changes the extension. This sets the names for the all object files we would end up with. We then use the list of names as a target and compile to object files, and overwrite the files with the new object file that we just compiled. Correct?

Comment: @Ungeheuer: No, the substitution reference does nothing at all to the files, it merely transforms the variables. It turns "source_dir/main.cpp" into "object_dir/main.o"; those are *file names*, not *files*. Once we have the string "object_dir/main.o", we can pass it to the pattern rule, which knows how to construct a file of that name.

Comment: Okay, so then is `OBJS` a single target (when we replace it with `$(OBJS)`)with a list of filenames that it will cycle through when it comes time to compile the C files into object files?

Comment: @Ungeheuer: No, `OBJS` is a list of filenames, which is the target of a pattern rule. If you want to build all of those files, you must invoke that rule for each of them (e.g. with a rule that has `$(OBJS)` among its prerequisites). I think you should play around with some simple makefiles before attempting something like this.